# Which JerseyClientBuilder to use?

Tags: jersey, dropwizard

So I'm developing an application on top of Dropwizard and in one component I have to call an external rest service. I want to do it using JerseyClient.

Now there are 2 implementations available, the one from dropwizard and one from jersey. Using the Builder I have to choose between

```
io.dropwizard.client.JerseyClientBuilder.JerseyClientBuilder
```

and

```
org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder
```

Now the former requires Environment as well as JerseyClientConfiguration being passed to it.

Is there a good reason for using the dropwizard implementation over the vanilla one? What's the difference (except the timeout)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging and asking around, got an answer (below). It seems that it is better to use the JerseyClientBuilder that comes with Dropwizard as it is better integrated:

- One can use JerseyClientConfiguration in order to configure the JerseyClientBuilder via the application configuration (service.yml file).
- Passing the Environment information enables use of the managed thread pool that is integrated within Dropwizard's lifecycle, so when Dropwizard gets shut down, so does the client.
- Dropwizard's Metrics get integrated into each client so you can see the latency and rate of calls for each one, as well as metrics around the thread pool sizes.